# Sudden PHP Error "Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream"

Tags: php, imap

Okay, this code 'was' working perfectly and then I started playing around with it in order to let others connect to their e-mails and as you do ran into a few open stream errors along the way due to various typos and such.

Since doing this, all of a sudden I can't connect to my e-mail at all? A short while back I was using the exact same connection code and then browsing my inbox.

I always get the "Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream" error.

This is strange as I'm using the exact same code as before, but since bumping into errors I can't connect whatsoever now. It also takes ages to respond.

Here is the code:

```
$mailbox = imap_open('{mail.artisancodesmith.com:143/notls}INBOX', 'admin@artisancodesmith.com', 'PASSWORD');

if ($mailbox) {
    $response = "MAIL MENU:<br>
        inbox: View your inbox.<br>
        compose: Compose an e-mail.<br>
        setup: Set your e-mail account's settings.";
    $next = "iorcmail";
}
```

NOTE: The PHP page is connecting to the e-mail on the same server.

***UPDATE:***
If I replace "mail.artisancodesmith.com" with "localhost" it works again!
I would preferably like to use my actual IMAP host - I'll see if it works again some time in the future I guess.
Thanks to all who helped. :)

Comment: Perhaps the remote server is refusing your connections because you've exceeded some allowed rate?

Comment: If that was the case how would I re-allow myself? Hosting24 is my host and I'm using CPanel X.

Comment: I've contacted my host and they say that this is not the case after looking into it thoroughly. :(

Comment: Try using [`imap_last_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-last-error.php) to see more about the error that occurred.

Comment: It says it cannot authenticate to the IMAP server, however the login details are identical to how they were when it was working. I'm stumped. Could it be to do with me not using imap_close() after opening a connection? I have no idea. :(

Answer (score 4):

Please use the below code to connect successfully,

```
$hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}";

$mailbox = imap_open($hostname, 'admin@artisancodesmith.com', 'PASSWORD');

if ($mailbox) 
{
    // do work....
}
```

Comment: I ran into this problem last week, adding novalidate-cert worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and here is how I solved it;

- Login to your gmail account, Under Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> Enable Imap.
- Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and select "Turn On"
- Go to: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and enable access.

after this, above code works for me....

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this an works perfectly fine for me

```
$inbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox", 'username', 'password')
             or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'All');
if($emails) {
    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';
    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);
    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
        $header =  imap_header($inbox, $email_number); 
        echo "<h1>data</h1>";
        echo "<pre>";print_r($message);
        echo "<h1>Message</h1>";
        echo "<pre>";print_r($message);
        echo "<h1>header</h1>";
        echo "<pre>";print_r($message);
        $overview[0]->seen;
        $overview[0]->subject;
        $overview[0]->from;
        $overview[0]->date;

    }
} 
/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe are you behind a proxy? if so, I guess you need to auth against it...

Answer (score 0):

```
resource imap_open(
    string $mailbox , 
    string $username , 
    string $password [, 
    int $options = 0 [, 
    int $n_retries = 0 [,  
    array $params = NULL ]]] 
)
```